# Right side panel

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have created a left side panel on my webpage i want to add another panel which comes out from the right side on the same page. 
please tell me the html, css as well as script for that.
PLEASE help!

Comment: Please do provide some code man

Comment: i want this thing to happen from right side

http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sidenav_push_opacity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginRight = "250px";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginRight= "0";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
```

```css
body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    transition: background-color .5s;
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s
}

.sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#main {
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 16px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<div id="main">
  <h2>Sidenav Push Example</h2>
  <p>Click on the element below to open the side navigation menu, and push this content to the right. Notice that we add a black see-through background-color to body when the sidenav is opened.</p>
  <span style="font-size:30px; position:absolute; right:0px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.header{
  width:100%; 
  height:100px;
  background:#ff8800;
}
.left{
  width:50%;
  float:left;
  height:100px;
  background:red;
}
.right{
  width:50%;
  float:left;
  height:100px;
  background:blue;
}
.bottom{
clear:both;
 width:100%;
  height:100px;
  background:#ff8855;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">Header</div>
<div class="left">Left Content</div>
<div class="right">Right Content</div>
<div class="bottom">Bottom Content</div>
```

Try This Is Example Of Your Requirement .

Comment: i want this thing to happen from right side

http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sidenav_push_opacity

Comment: k check Once At My Next Ans

Comment: I am Added Snippet Check Once

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("main").style.marginRight= "0";
enter code here
```

Add This code At Your Script

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
display:table-cell;
```

to both panels. 
Or for first add

```
float:left;
```

and for second panel add

```
float:right;
```

Comment: i want this thing to happen from right side

http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sidenav_push_opacity

Answer (score 0):

Save this as index.css

```
    .btn-dark {
        border-radius: 0;
        color: #fff;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    }

    .btn-dark:hover,
    .btn-dark:focus,
    .btn-dark:active {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    }

    .btn-light {
        border-radius: 0;
        color: #333;
        background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
    }

    .btn-light:hover,
    .btn-light:focus,
    .btn-light:active {
        color: #333;
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    }

    #sidebar-wrapper {
        z-index: 1000;
        position: fixed;
        right: 0;
        width: 250px;
        height: 100%;
        margin-right: -250px;
        overflow-y: auto;
        background: #222;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
        -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
        -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
        -o-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
        transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
    }

    .sidebar-nav {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        width: 250px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
    }

    .sidebar-nav li {
        text-indent: 20px;
        line-height: 40px;
    }

    .sidebar-nav li a {
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #999;
    }

    .sidebar-nav li a:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #fff;
        background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    }

    .sidebar-nav li a:active,
    .sidebar-nav li a:focus {
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
        height: 55px;
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 55px;
    }

    .sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
        color: #999;
    }

    .sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
        color: #fff;
        background: none;
    }

    #menu-toggle {
        z-index: 1;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
    }

    #sidebar-wrapper.active {
        right: 250px;
        width: 250px;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
        -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
        -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
        -o-transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
        transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
    }

    .toggle {
        margin: 5px 5px 0 0;
    }
```

This is the html document. Save this as index.html.

```
    <link href="index.css" rel="styleshet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <a id="menu-toggle" href="#" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg toggle"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
    <nav id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
            <a id="menu-close" href="#" class="btn btn-light btn-lg pull-right toggle"><i class="material-icons">close</i></a>
            <li>
                <a onclick=$("#menu-close").click();>Item</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a onclick=$("#menu-close").click();>Item</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a onclick=$("#menu-close").click();>Item</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <script>
    // Closes the sidebar menu
    $("#menu-close").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#sidebar-wrapper").toggleClass("active");
    });

    // Opens the sidebar menu
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#sidebar-wrapper").toggleClass("active");
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i want this thing to happen from right side

http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sidenav_push_opacity

Answer (score 0):

```js
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
```

```css
body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    transition: background-color .5s;
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s
}

.sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#main {
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 16px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<div id="main">
  <h2>Sidenav Push Example</h2>
  <p>Click on the element below to open the side navigation menu, and push this content to the right. Notice that we add a black see-through background-color to body when the sidenav is opened.</p>
  <span style="font-size:30px; position:absolute; right:0px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
</div>
```

Comment: as soon as i click the open button panel goes fine but the background text still moves to the right ...let it also move in the same direction as panel

Comment: k I am Trying To Fix

Comment: Check My Next Snippet

Answer (score 0):

Change marginleft To MarginRight In Script

```js
    function openNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
        document.getElementById("main").style.marginRight = "250px";
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
    }

    function closeNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
        document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }
```

```css
  body {
        font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
        transition: background-color .5s;
    }

    .sidenav {
        height: 100%;
        width: 0;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        background-color: #111;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        transition: 0.5s;
        padding-top: 60px;
    }

    .sidenav a {
        padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 25px;
        color: #818181;
        display: block;
        transition: 0.3s
    }

    .sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
        color: #f1f1f1;
    }

    .sidenav .closebtn {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 25px;
        font-size: 36px;
        margin-left: 50px;
    }

    #main {
        transition: margin-left .5s;
        padding: 16px;
    }

    @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
      .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
      .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
    }
```

```html
    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Services</a>
      <a href="#">Clients</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>

    <div id="main">
      <h2>Sidenav Push Example</h2>
      <p>Click on the element below to open the side navigation menu, and push this content to the right. Notice that we add a black see-through background-color to body when the sidenav is opened.</p>
      <span style="font-size:30px; position:absolute; right:0px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Cool..thanks 
but the text remains as it is after clicking on open once. let it take the whole page (just like before clicking the open button) as when i click cross button from the panel

Answer (score 0):

```
//**Add This In Your Script** 
function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginRight= "0";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
```