# How to remove an unexpected scrollbar at the bottom of browser

Tags: html, jquery, css, scrollbar

I have a menu and want to hide it from the right side of a browser.  When a button is clicked, the menu will show and move from right to left.

Everything is working as expect, however, a horizontal bar shows up at the bottom of the browser when the menu is hidden!

I tried to add `overflow: hidden` but it doesn't work.

```js
$(function(){
  $('button').click(function(){
    $('.head').toggleClass('show');
  })
})
```

```css
.head {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
button {
float: right;
background: black;
color: white;
}
.menu {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  right: -290px;
  top: 60px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
                -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
                -o-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
                transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
}
.head.show .menu {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="head">
  <button>Show Menu</button>
  <div class="menu"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `overflow-x: hidden;` on the body worked for me

Comment: That's the scroll bar because you're positioning the menu outside the window.

Comment: That is right, menu's position is out side of the window.  However, if I hide the menu from the left, I don't see a scroll bar at the bottom.

Comment: `overflow-x: hidden;` on the body solves this. *" if I hide the menu from the left, I don't see a scroll bar at the bottom."* - please ask another question, we don't even know what you mean by hiding from left

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the body overflow to hidden and it will hide the scroll bar.

```
body {
 overflow:hidden;
}
```

I also moved your div in absolute (.menu) out of you container (.head). I think its better way to do this kind of thinks

```js
$(function(){
  $('button').click(function(){
    $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
    $('.menu').toggleClass('show');
    
    if (!$('.menu').hasClass('show')) {
      $('body').attr('style', '');
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.container {
 position:absolute;
   width: 90%;
}
.head {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
button {
float: right;
background: black;
color: white;
}
.menu {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: green;
  position: fixed;
  right: -300px;
  top: 70px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
}
.menu.show {
  right: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="head">
  <button>Show Menu</button>
</div>
<div class="menu"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, The_Death_Raw!  I wonder why if I hide the menu from the left, I don't have a scroll bar at the bottom?  and beside setting body overflow to hidden, do we have another solution?  because setting body overflow to hidden may effect some other pages across the site.

Comment: @abcidd i changed a bit my code to use overflow hidden only when showing your menu div. You can answer here maybe : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39263735/right-side-panel

Comment: Thanks, The_Death_Raw! It would work only after clicking, but before clicking, the scroll bar is there

Comment: @ the_Death_Raw, I just found if I change display: absolute to fixed, the scrollbar will disappear.

Comment: Good job :) @abcidd

Comment: I edited my answer, Your right ! my bad sorry... @abcidd